# Blackberry Send & Receive Data Via Post Method

Tags: json, post, blackberry, httpconnection

Sending Data on server via POST Method.
And receiving the JSON Response.
Blackberry - Answered.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuffer postData = new StringBuffer();

            httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

            postData.append("?username="+username);
            postData.append("&password="+pass);
            postData.append("&projectcode="+projectid);
            String encodedData = postData.toString();

            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",(new Integer(encodedData.length())).toString());
            byte[] postDataByte = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            OutputStream out = httpConn.openOutputStream(); 
            out.write(postDataByte);
            out.close();

            httpConn.getResponseCode();

            is = httpConn.openInputStream(); 

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int ch = 0;

            while (ch != -1) {
                ch = is.read();
                buffer.append((char) ch);
            }

            String json = buffer.toString();

            Dialog.alert("Received Json: "+json);
```

Comment: There are a few things I don't like, but the worst is that in order for this code to issue the Dialog.alert(..) that it does at the end, it must be running on the Event Thread, and of course it should not do that because it is blocking with network activity.  This is not production code.

Comment: @PeterStrange It was just for debugging purpose to show the output on screen. and yes this is not production code i agree